# Can $u\in W^{1,2}_0$, $\Delta u\in L^2$, $u\geq 0$ be approximated by a sequence smooth function $u_k\geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, approximation, laplacian

Assume that $\Omega\in R^3$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain. $u\in W^{1,2}_{0}$, $\Delta u\in L^2$, $u\geq 0$. Is it possible to approximate u by a sequence of nonnegative smooth functions $u_k$, $u_k|_{\partial \Omega}=0$ such that $\|u-u_k\|_{L^2}+\|\Delta (u-u_k)\|_{L^2}\to 0$?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Your assumptions on $u$  imply that $u\in W^{2,2}$ (2nd order derivatives of $u$ can be written as Riesz transforms of the Laplacian, which is a bounded transform on $L^2$). What happens if  you convolve $u$ with a nonnegative mollifier $\phi_\epsilon$, where $\epsilon=\epsilon(x)$ is a smooth function vanishing on the boundary? ... As an aside: it helps to use more than one tag. There is a  `sobolev-spaces` tag, which would draw attention of relevant people more reliably than `approximation`.